# posting html form data to java class using javascript after validating using javascript in jsp file

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jsp

I am having trouble posting data gotten from a html form created in a jsp file using javascript and posting it to a java class using javascript after validating the form data using javascript. I was trying to find an alternative from Ajax since I am not familiar with the tools but if you are familiar with ajax javascript tools I would appreciate it if you could point me into the right direction on where I an learn how to use it.
Anyone who can help? Its for a class project. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Javascript:

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
 function validateInventory() {
var imei_no = document.form.imei_no.value;
var phone_name = document.form.phone_name.value;
var phone_storage = document.form.phone_storage.value;
var phone_color = document.form.phone_color.value;
var phone_buyingprice = document.form.phone_buyingprice.value;
var valid = true;

if (imei_no.value.length > 15 || imei_no.value.length <= 0||imei_no) {
    alert("Invalid No. of digits in IMEI");
    form.imei_no.focus();
    valid = false;

} else {
    if (isNaN(imei_no) == true
            || isNaN(phone_buyingprice) == true) {
        alert("Please enter number value in IMEI/Buying Price!");
        imei_no.focus();
        phone_buyingprice.focus();
        valid = false;
    } else if (imei_no = null ||imei_no = 0 || phone_name_value == ""
            || phone_storage_value == "" || phone_color_value == ""
            || phone_buyingprice_value == 0|| phone_buyingprice_value == null) {
        alert("Some entries are empty. Please recheck your Input");
        valid = false;
    }
}
var cofirmInput= window.confirm("Is your Input correct?");
if(confirmInput==true){
    alert("Input succesful!!!");
    return valid; 
}else{
    valid=false;
}

};
function resetInventory() {
var resetForm = window
        .confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
if (resetForm == true) {
    alert("Reset Successful!!!");
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
    };
```

};

Here is my html form in my jsp:

```
<form action=# method=post name=InventoryForm id=InventoryForm
            onreset="return resetInventory()"
            onsubmit="return validateInventory()">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" id=InventoryFormTable>
                <tr>
                    <th>IMEI NO</th>
                    <th>PHONE NAME</th>
                    <th>PHONE STORAGE</th>
                    <th>PHONE COLOR</th>
                    <th>PHONE BUYING PRICE</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type=text name=imei_no id=imei_no></td>
                    <td><select name=phone_name id=phone_name>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="iPhone X">iPhone X</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 8">iPhone 8</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 8 Plus">iPhone 8Plus</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 7">iPhone 7</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 7 Plus">iPhone 7Plus</option>
                            <option value="iPhone SE">iPhone SE</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 6">iPhone 6</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 6 Plus">iPhone 6Plus</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 6s">iPhone 6s</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 6s Plus">iPhone 6sPlus</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 5s">iPhone 5s</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 5c">iPhone 5c</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 4">iPhone 4</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 4s">iPhone 4s</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option>
                            <option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select name=phone_storage id=phone_storage>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value=16GB>16 GB</option>
                            <option value=3216GB>32 GB</option>
                            <option value=64GB>64 GB</option>
                            <option value=128GB>128 GB</option>
                            <option value=256GB>256 GB</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type=text name=phone_color id=phone_color></td>
                    <td><input type=text name=phone_buyingingprice
                        id=phone_buyingingprice></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan=6><div class=button>
                            <input type=submit id=submit value=submit>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=reset
                                id=reset value=reset>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>




        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Servlet`. To get started, you can start from: [Servlet Tutorial](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/servlet-tutorial/).

What you can do is fire an [XHR](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) request (or AJAX.. same thing) on the form's submission to your `Servlet` (write in action attribure the path to your `Servlet`). When the request comes to the `Servlet`, you can do multiple `request.getParameter` for all the form data to get the form values and do whatever else you want with the information (this is your `Java` class that you want to have your form information). Then you can do `request.getRequestDispatcher` to redirect to wherever you want (optional).

Hope this paints a picture.

Comment: I found a way to add a servlet dependency in the maven project I am working on so I that my servlet can intercept all requests and determine how to handle them based on how the directory is ending.